# Unity trigger reference to an other script

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, reference, scene, prefab

I have a prefab with a Trigger and want the OnTriggerStay methode in a gamobject in the Gamescene. Does someone know how i can make a reference from the scene to the trigger of the prefab and call the OnTrigger methodes in the scenesripts?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The trigger is a Collider, so you can get a reference to the trigger of the prefab by using `prefabReference.GetComponent<Collider>()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully understand your question.

But OnTriggerStay method working when you have two objects and while intersection happening between objects OnTriggerStay method is working.
By the way one objects collider attribute should be selected as trigger.

If you want to trigger events from another script. You can create an event system. Unity have lovely tutorial for this one.

Please check this tutorial, if that is what you need.
https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/create-a-simple-messaging-system-with-events#

Comment: OK thanks, I will look. I mean that I know how to use a trigger. But if I have a trigger on a prefab and different objects in a scene which should start different things if the trigger is entered. And so I need to know in the Scene with which of the objects the prefab collides and this would be easy if i could get the OnTriggerEnter or Stay in the script in the scene. But thanks.

Comment: @Kes If something is colliding with something in the scene it's not a prefab. You probably mean to call it a **gameObject** or an **instance** rather than a prefab. [See here for more info](http://answers.unity.com/answers/46127/view.html)